# Python, mysql, вывести сообщения datetime которых < актуального времени на 1 час

Tags: python, mysql, дата, datetime

Например в БД есть такие данные:

```
id  |        date         |  message
1   2018-11-13 12:00:00      Сообщение 1
2   2018-11-13 13:00:00      Сообщение 2
3   2018-11-13 14:00:00      Сообщение 3
```

Например актуальный datetime 2018-11-13 14:00:00

Как можно вывести только те даты, которые меньше от актуального datetime хотя бы на 1 час? В моем случае это Сообщение 2 и Сообщение 1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3681365/5741205

Comment: я не уверен, что понимаю что значит `ряды datetime которых < 1 часа` - можете пояснить?

Comment: подправил вопрос, возможно так будет понятнее

Comment: Т.е. "актуальное время" - это не текущее, а заданное? Как оно задаётся в таком случае?

Comment: просто при запуске скрипта берется серверное время и дата такого формата "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

Comment: `Сообщение 1` отличается от "актуального времени" на __2 часа__  - почему оно попадает в выборку?

Comment: извиняюсь, подправил, "хотя бы" на один час

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
q="""SELECT id, date, message FROM table_name WHERE date < DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)"""

cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute(q, (actual_date,))  # NOTE: `actual_date` should be an instance of [datetime]

for row in cur.fetchall():
    print(row)
```